# What is a "Big Wheel" in Animorphs 8: The Alien?

Tags: meaning

For context, Marco is bringing Aximili-Esgarrouth-Isthill, an alien, to visit his house for the first time. Looking around the suburban US neighbourhood, Ax notices something, and the following exchange takes place:

> Also, some houses were decorated with items that had been placed on the grass.
> "What is that decoration?" I asked.
> Marco followed the direction of my gaze. Then he rolled his eyes upwards. "That's a Big Wheel."
> "It is very attractive. Very colourful."
> "Uh-huh. I'd love to tell you how it works, but it's the very height of human technology, so it's secret. Primitive races could get hold of Big Wheels, and then who knows what might happen?

(Page 61 and 62 of my UK edition).

I've tried searching for lawn ornaments called a Big Wheel, but they mostly lead to repurposed wagon wheels or similar. I'm aware of pinwheels; is Big Wheel perhaps a brand name of pinwheel manufacturer that would have been familiar to the book's original US audience? I note that it is capitalised both times it occurs. Or is it something entirely different that I'm unaware of?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Google brings up Big Wheel immediately as a toy. *Lawn ornament* is a joke.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like one of these, as per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_wheel_(tricycle)):

> **Big Wheel** is a brand of low-riding tricycles, made mostly of plastic, with a larger front wheel. Introduced by Louis Marx and Company in 1969 and manufactured in Girard, Pennsylvania, Big Wheel was a very popular toy in the 1970s in the United States, partly because of its low cost and partly because consumer groups said it was a safer alternative to the traditional tricycle or bicycle. The large front wheel also made it a stable, easier tricycle to ride for children.
>
> [image: yellow, red & blue tricycle with large front wheel]

The trikes themselves are called "Big Wheels" too and kids leave them outside in driveways or on the lawn all the time, as kids are wont to do with their toys.